# unable to see cucumber with java in plugins of IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber

I'm new member for IntelliJ. I am trying to install a plugin for Cucumber in IntelliJ IDE.

Following are the steps which I am trying:

1. File > Settings (Ctrl+Alt+S)
2. From left hand pane, landing on Plugins tab.
3. In Search box, I am trying to search "Cucumber for Java".

But no result is displaying for same.

Can anyone help me on this ?

On search I am not able to see the option Cucumber for java, which is visible here in given [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869851/intellij-with-cucumber-java-and-step-definition-location).

Answer (score 1):

Please [see the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/installing-updating-and-uninstalling-repository-plugins.html).

Use the **Browse Repositories** button.

**Cucumber for Java** plug-in is available out of the box in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.

For IntelliJ IDEA Community edition it's available as a free plug-in that you need to install:

[image: install]

In case IDE doesn't see the plugins list, please check the [proxy settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/http-proxy.html). Disabling [this option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVUjG.png) may also help.

It's also possible to download install plugins manually from disk. Make sure to get the version which is compatible with your IntelliJ IDEA build.

Cucumber for Java can be [downloaded here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7212-cucumber-for-java).

The version compatible with IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.x is available by [this link](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/download?rel=true&updateId=43535).

Please also note that there is no Cucumber for Java plug-in version that is compatible with [IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2 EAP builds](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/) at the moment. If you need this plug-in, please use [2018.1.4 release version](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html).

Comment: Yeah, I did try that as well and even tried to search there. But no luck. It says "Nothing to show".

Comment: @1164444 please see the updated answer, I've tried to cover all possible problem cases and provided the alternative installation instructions.